# smooth coloring algorithm for the mandelbrot set

Tags: algorithm, colors, tkinter, fractals, mandelbrot

I know there are a lot of questions alrady answered about this. However, mine varies slightly. Whenever we implement the smooth coloring algorithim as I understand it.

```
mu = 1 + n + math.log2(math.log2(z))  / math.log2(2)
```

where n is the escape iteration and 2 is the power z is to, and if im not mistaken z is the modulus of the complex number at that escape iteration. We then use this renormalized escape value in our linear interpolation between colors to produce a smoothly banded mandelbrot set. I've seen answers to other questions about this where we run this value through a HSB to RGB conversion, however I still fail to understand how this would provide a smooth gradient of colors and how to implement this in python.

However, whenever I attempted to implement this it produces floating point RGB values, but there isn't an image format that I know of, besides a .tiff file, that would support this, and if we round off to integers we still have unsmooth banding. So how is this supposed to produce a smoothly banded image if we cannot directly use the RGB values it produces? Example code of what I tried below, since I don't undertand fully how to implement this I made an attempt at a solution that somewhat produces smooth banding. This produces a somewhat smoothly banded image between two colors blue for the full set and a progressively whiter color the further we zoom in on the set to the point where at a certain depth everything just appears blurred. Since I'm using tkinter to do this I had to convert the RGB values to hex to be able to draw them to the canvas.

I;m computing the set recursively, and in my other function (not posted below) i am setting the window width and height then iterating over these for the pixels of the tkinter window and computing this recursion in the inner loop.

```
def linear_interp(self, color_1, color_2, i):

    r = (color_1[0] * (1 - i)) + (color_2[0] * i)
    g = (color_1[1] * (1 - i)) + (color_2[1] * i)
    b = (color_1[2] * (1 - i)) + (color_2[2] * i)
    rgb_list = [r, g, b]
    for value in rgb_list:
        if value > MAX_COLOR:
            rgb_list[rgb_list.index(value)] = MAX_COLOR
        if value < 0:
            rgb_list[rgb_list.index(value)] = abs(value)

    return (int(rgb_list[0]), int(rgb_list[1]), 
            int(rgb_list[2]))

def rgb_to_hex(self, color):
    return "#%02x%02x%02x" % color

def mandel(self, x, y, z, iteration):
    bmin = 100
    bmax = 255
    power_z = 2

    mod_z = math.sqrt((z.real * z.real) + (z.imag * z.imag))
    #If its not in the set or we have reached the maximum depth
    if  abs(z) >= float(power_z) or iteration == DEPTH:
        z = z
        if iteration > 255:
            factor = (iteration / DEPTH) * 255
        else:
            factor = iteration

        logs = math.log2(math.log2(abs(z) + 1 ) / math.log2(power_z))
        r = g = math.floor(factor + 5 - logs)

        b = bmin + (bmax - bmin) * r / 255
        rgb = (abs(r), abs(g), abs(round(b)))
        self.canvas.create_line(x, y, x + 1, y + 1,
                                fill = self.rgb_to_hex(rgb))

    else:

        z = (z * z) + self.c
        self.mandel(x, y, z, iteration + 1)

    return z
```

Comment: can you show a graph of values along for example line from c= 2 to c= 0.25 like : https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:P_hot_inv.gif

Answer (score 0):

The difference between colors #000000, #010000, ..., #FE0000, #FF0000 is so small that you obtain a smooth gradient from black to red. Hence, simply round your values: Suppose your smoothened color values of your smoothness function range from 0 to (excl) 1, then you simply use 
    (int) (value * 256)